# Get storyboard id of the current viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uikit, storyboard

Probably a stupid question, but I can't find a solution.
I need to save the current storyboard id, so when navigating to another viewcontroller I will know who was the sender viewcontroller.
I thought to use storyboardid.
I saw a lot of answers that use this id to create an instanted of the viewcontroler. like this:

```swift
let view = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyStoryboardId") as UIViewController
```

but I can't find a way to get it.

I am in button action, so I can see in the Debug windows, that:

`self.window.rootViewController.storyboard`

has something that hold the storyboard id ->
`identifiertoUINibMap`.
But I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Hint : Use restorationIdentifier

Comment: Personally, when I want to do something on the basis of what the presenting view controller is, rather than using the storyboard id, I would test for what is class the view controller (e.g. `if foo is SomeViewController { ... }`). Or I set some property in th presenting view controller. Or use delegate-protocol pattern. It's hard to advise you on the best solution without more details about what broader problem you are trying to solve. But attempting to get the storyboard identifier would not generally be my first approach.

Comment: @RajaKishan I tried this but it returns nil. I tried `self.restorationIdentifier` and `self.window?.rootViewController?.restorationIdentifier`

Comment: you have to first set restorationIdentifier from the storyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :-

```
extension UIViewController {
    var storyboardId: String {
        return value(forKey: "storyboardIdentifier") as? String ?? "none"
    }
}
```